# What the difference of module.system=haste and module.system=node in Facebook's flow

Tags: flowtype

I work on a project which is using Facebook's flow. In the Advanced Configuration of flow and there are two choices for the [options] heading (module.system=haste and module.system=node).

Now I would like to know what is the difference of "haste" and "node".

Answer (score 6):

They are 2 different ways of resolving modules: `haste` is the module system used by react-native for packaging (similar to browserify or webpack for browsers):

https://github.com/facebook/node-haste

The `node` module system is the method used by node internally.

As for how they actually *differ*: unfortunately `haste` does not have extensive documentation yet.  AFAICT the primary difference is that `haste` can resolve packages references (e.g. `require('underscore')`) to a single module, whereas `node` will actually use a different module for each sub-package.  Basically: with `node` you can end up with multiple versions of say, `underscore` in a single program, whereas with `haste` only one version of `underscore` is put into the final package.

This can result in subtle differences if there are multiple versions of a module in a project, though apparently `haste` is [becoming more compatible with existing node behavior](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/04/17/react-native-v0.4.html).

Comment: Whatever `haste` was, it seems kind of abortive, because the repo now claims it is unsupported/deprecated and Facebook is no longer using it.