# What is the Haste module map in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

When I launch :

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/MyProject/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

I have an error which says that :

```
Unable to resolve module `util` from `/Users/canatac/RNProjects/<MyProject>/node_modules/<A_Module>/lib/Bot.js`: Module `<A_Module>` does not exist in the Haste module map.
```

But what is a Haste module map ?

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I'm getting a similar error and for the life of me I cant find any documentation on this "Haste Module Map" , what it does, or how to fix it.. This is why these JS frameworks drive me so nuts. The whole damn ecosystem is bonkers

Answer (score 1):

Same error occured for me once, and [that Github thread](https://github.com/zetachang/react-native-dotenv/issues/39#issuecomment-384593005) has helped me.

> I had a similar problem - what helped was running npm start -- --reset-cache command.

Based on the question itself, it is somehow connected to `/tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`, ergo React Native Packager.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I learned that trick. I also see that Haste Map is the dependency graph. But written with capital 'H', I wonder if it's a kind a concept or reference of package dependency map.

Answer (score 1):

I may found an interpretation.
Haste is a deprecated Facebook dependency management system for static resources [as this GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebookarchive/node-haste) suggests.

[This post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078638/what-the-difference-of-module-system-haste-and-module-system-node-in-facebooks) tells us Haste is an alternative to Node.

Then, I may conclude that a Haste Map is a map of all static dependency references of a node project AND as a deprecated system must be avoided in favor of Node module system.

Comment: Not deprecated...its now `facebook/jest/packages/jest-haste-map`.