# Flow+Webstorm "Cannot resolve module"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, types

I have an existing project where we integrated Flow's type system into the react side. The project is electron-based so, by definition, a mono-repo. We ran in to all kinds of issues getting flow to recognize import statements.

node_modules imports would fail:

```
import _ from 'lodash'; // Flow: Cannot resolve module lodash
```

And more importantly, we wanted absolute pathing relative to our project:

```
import {MyComponent} from 'src/component/myComponent'; 
// Flow: Cannot resolve module src...
```

Finding a solution on this took a bit of digging, and the documentation is a little lacking in some areas, so I want to throw a compiled list of what actually worked out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR;

Get flow set up on webstorm so it is giving you module errors

Set up flow globally, and point webstorm's js settings to use Flow and point it at the global copy of flow-bin (not even the exe, just the dir)

add the following options to .flowconfig:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='^src\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/\1'
module.system=haste
```

---

## Full version

## A few basic steps have to be done to get flow to work in webstorm at all:

### Install flow-bin globally

Several sources made the claim that flow-bin runs better globally

Install flow-bin globally

```
yarn global add flow-bin
or
npm i -g flow-bin
```

> Double check that it gave you a current version of flow-bin, this
>   refused to work on 0.75.0 or earlier

### Set up Webstorm's flow executable

- On Webstorm: File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript
- Choose Flow as the JavaScript language version
- Find where your package manager (yarn or npm) stores global files

> On Windows+yarn this is C:/Users/[your username]/AppData/Local/Yarn/Cache/v1
>
> On Windows+NPM this is C:/Users/fish/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules

That makes my flow path:

```
C:/Users/[your username]/AppData/Local/Yarn/Cache/v1/npm-flow-bin-[whatever]/
```

- On Webstorm's JavaScript settings, Target the Flow package or executable to the global flow path we just found
- Apply, ok

## Setting up Flow's .flowconfig

### .flowconfig setup side notes

- I have a root git project with 2 parts, react, and electron. Flow does things based on where you put the .flowconfig file.
- If it includes "all=true", remove that line and go add // @Flow to your files you want flow to check (otherwise it will start indexing all of node_modules

### Reproducing my problem

- Put .flowconfig in your react directory
- Enjoy all the "Flow: Cannot import module" squiggly lines of doom

### Solution to the module problem

This is my current .flowconfig

```
[ignore]
.*/build/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
module.name_mapper='^src\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/\1'
module.system=haste

[strict]
```

### Why does this work?

Tells the name mapper to resolve modules that begin with src/ to the src/ directory so your absolute paths to your project's files work:

```
module.name_mapper='^src\/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/\1'
```

Tells flow to use the "haste" module system:

```
module.system=haste
```

The haste module system step is important because otherwise it doesn't know that by 'lodash' you mean './node_modules/lodash'. Telling it to use haste means it will properly find your import statements. [More info on haste available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078638/what-the-difference-of-module-system-haste-and-module-system-node-in-facebooks)

Comment: Are you sure using haste here is a good idea? From the looks of it, [haste is deprecated, and FB is no longer using it](https://github.com/facebookarchive/node-haste). I always thought it only still existed in flow for legacy reasons

Comment: Also, to get proper typings for lodash and other libraries, I recommend looking into using [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed)

Comment: Correct on the flow-typed, but that's not the problem I was fixing. My issue was broken module import lines in the code files because Flow didn't know where to look, not broken type definitions.

Comment: The canonical resolve_dirname does not fix the import problem.